# stylus - middleware not compiling the `styl` file

Tags: node.js, stylus, node.js-connect

I integrated the `stylus` with middleware. but there is no `compile` function called at all..

1) How to make `compile` method to work

2) How to update 'tcp.css' each time i update 'tcp.styl` file modified

here is my code :

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    stylus = require('stylus');

var app = connect();

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src     : __dirname + '/app/css', //inside i have tcp.styl
    dest    : __dirname + '/app/css', //i require tcp.css
    force   : true,
    compile : function(str, path) {
        console.log('compiled'); //not called at all..
      return stylus(str, path)
        .set('filename', path) //file name i need to update as 'tcp.css'?
        .set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true);
    }
}));

app.use(serveStatic("app"));
app.listen(5000, function () {console.log("HI", __dirname);}); //works!
```

file structure:
[image: file structure image]

Comment: Are you actually requesting the `/css/tcp.css` URL? Your snippet has no home/index page. What happens if you run `curl --verbose localhost:5000/css/tcp.css`?

Comment: It is loading my `css` file what i have. there is no issues. (but the css file not made by compile function, i made it manually and kept there..

Comment: Double check your file layout and `__dirname`. What folder and file contains the above snippet? Is it your project root or the "app" directory? The more details about the complete filesystem layout you can post, the more accurately and easily we can help you troubleshoot. It's probably a simple mistake somewhere, but just that snippet is not enough info to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your app structure. It doesn't match your configuration. You have your file at `./public/stylus/tcp.styl` but that needs to match your `src` stylus configuration option. Set it up with this structure:

- move your stylus code to `./public/css/tcp.styl`

  - keeping the .styl and .css file next to each other simplifies things.
- stylus middleware option: `src: __dirname + '/public'`

  - remove the stylus middleware `dest`. It will default to the same as `src` and everything will be simpler.
- URI to load `/css/tcp.css`
- compiled css will end up in `./public/css/tcp.css`, to be served by your static middleware after the stylus middleware compiles it.

Comment: Yes, this is done. Note: do you have any idea to refresh my `.styl` file or `js` file on change to reload the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example, but in express, that would do what you are asking.

root directory 'app' and it's files

```
 app.js   index.jade  public
```

public/stylesheets contains, one .styl file

```
 public/stylesheets/tcp.styl
```

index.jade is being connected with compiled .css

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/tcp.css")
```

add one paragraph in a index.jade and style it in tcp.styl and when you run a server you'll get your file auto compiled from tcp.styl -> tcp.css. And stylesheets folder will contain two files

```
tcp.styl  tcp.css
```

Hope it helps.

App.js file looks like that

```js
var express = require('express'),
    nib = require('nib'),
    stylus = require('stylus');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public',
    compile: function compile(str, path) {
       return stylus(str)
       .set('filename', path)
       .use(nib())
    }
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('../index');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: Ok, what is the issue to make this happen with `connect` server?